# Is Scala Either really a Monad

Tags: scala, monads, either

I was wondering if scala `Either` is really a `Monad` in Category Theory sense?. I know that Monads should have `bind` and `return` methods. What is `Either`'s `bind` then?

Comment: http://scabl.blogspot.com/2013/02/monads-in-scala-1.html:  *The binding operation, as a Scala function, would have the following signature:*
`def bind[A, B](Maybe[A])(A => Maybe[B]): Maybe[B]`

Comment: I would argue that Haskell `Maybe` in Scala is more like an `Option` than `Either`. `Either` is cooproduct of types.

Comment: Read the article.  It addresses that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it really is - otherwise it would be in scalaz-outlaws. `Either`'s `bind` is defined something like:

```
trait Either[A, B] {
  def bind[C](f: B => Either[A, C]) = this match {
    case Right(b) => f(b)
    case Left(a) => Left(a)
  }
}
```

(in practice it's defined via a typeclass, but the above definition would work)

I guess it's more proper to say that for a fixed `A`, the type `({type L[B]=Either[A, B]})#L` forms a `Monad`, so `Either` is more a class of `Monads` than a `Monad` in its own right, but that's an exceedingly technical distinction.

But it really is a `Monad`; it satisfies all the monad laws.

Comment: So it is more precise to say that `Right` and `Left` are `Monads` whereas `Either` itself is not, but its subclasses?

Comment: No, that's wrong. `Left` on its own is not a `Monad` at all, and `Right` on its own is just the identity `Monad`. If you want to be precise a `Monad` is not really a trait (which after all is not a mathematical concept) so much as a set and a pair of operations. So it's more like "for any `A`, the set of all `Either[A, B]` forms a monad under the operations `bind=...` and `point=...`).

Comment: As of Scala 2.12, Either became right biased. So technically, Either at the root became more uniform with the other Monad implementations (in that one didn't have to select a projection from which to then further Monad operations).

Comment: @Imm @goral One could define an instance of `Monad` just for `Left` (although it would probably look a whole lot like the instance of `Monad` for `Id` in `scalaz`) so it's not incorrect to say that Left "is" a `Monad`. But certainly, an instance of `Monad` can be defined for `Either` (which is usually what's done), so saying that `Either` is not a `Monad` is incorrect.